# Microsoft Azure Face Comparison

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

We have decided to use aws/azure cognitive services specifically for face recognition/comparison. I am doing some evaluation which fits best for our scenarios.

Both work fine and are abl to compare images and give confidence / similarity percentages accurately.

I have a problem specifically with Azure...
I have 3 images a frontal face picture (this is the reference picture) , 2 other picture where i have turned slightly towards my right and left.

When i test the comparsion on the demo site of azure the confidence score is high (0.9) but when i am testing the comparsion using the api it gives a score of 0.7.

Although both detected the face's are identical i am not sure why there is a difference ?

"Demo site -- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/face/#verification"

I have also tried changing the detection model from the default detection_01 to detection_02.

I am using the REST api for this and as instructed in the samples....
i call the detect api for both the images and get faceid's before calling the verify api passing the faceid's

Should i do a grouping first to get a higher score ?

I am using the sample source code that is already available in azure sites. Let me know if you need to see the code, i will add it in the question.

Please do let me know your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: I'd imagine this is more a question for Microsoft support and not so much Stack Overflow.

Comment: Which region are you using for the API test?

Comment: i am using the westcentralus . If it is a question for support then i can close the question and go through the microsoft channels.

Comment: I am going to check with the MS support team on this. Wc can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen with azure face recog service is that it works only when the image is facing towards the camera. Even a slight turn to the let or right does not return the same results and sometimes has returned in the likes of 'images not identical'.